# Trying to get Authorize.net XML working from John Conde Class

Tags: php, xml, curl, authorize.net

I am using Authorize.net XML Class from:

https://github.com/stymiee/Authorize.Net-XML

But I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in [no active file]:0 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in [no active file] on line 0

I know I need to put a (string) something in the class to make it work I believe.

This is my php code after payment is submitted:

```
if ($xml->messages->resultCode == 'Ok' && $xml->isSuccessful()) {
    $_SESSION['transID'] = $xml->transactionResponse->transId;
} else {
    $_SESSION['ErrorMSGTXT'] = $xml->messages->message->text;
    $_SESSION['ErrorERRORTXT'] = $xml->transactionResponse->errors->error->errorText;
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign an instance of [SimpleXMLElement](http://docs.php.net/simplexml) to _SESSION. SimpleXMLELement "has" a `serialize` method that just throws the exception you've got.
Instead of persisting the instance itself you probably just want to store the string representation of that node (e.g. by [casting it to string](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php)).

```
if ($xml->messages->resultCode == 'Ok' && $xml->isSuccessful()) {
    $_SESSION['transID'] = (string)$xml->transactionResponse->transId;
} else {
    $_SESSION['ErrorMSGTXT'] = (string)$xml->messages->message->text;
    $_SESSION['ErrorERRORTXT'] = (string)$xml->transactionResponse->errors->error->errorText;
    exit();
}
```